# android volley error whle using imageloader

Tags: android, android-volley

what is the problem of my below code ? I am following up [android tutorial](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/volley/request.html)
I am having `nullpointerexception` in this code line , what might be the problem?

```
mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, mImageLoader);
```

this is the full code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

  final String IMAGE_URL =
            "http://developer.android.com/images/training/system-ui.png";

//Instantiate the cache
Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap

//Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

//Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);

//Start the queue
mRequestQueue.start();


ImageLoader mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new LruBitmapCache(
            LruBitmapCache.getCacheSize(mContext)));
mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, mImageLoader);
}
```

this is the singleton

```
package com.example.p;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageCache;

public class LruBitmapCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap>
        implements ImageCache {

    public LruBitmapCache(int maxSize) {
        super(maxSize);
    }

    public LruBitmapCache(Context ctx) {
        this(getCacheSize(ctx));
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
    }

    // Returns a cache size equal to approximately three screens worth of images.
    public static int getCacheSize(Context ctx) {
        final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = ctx.getResources().
                getDisplayMetrics();
        final int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        final int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        // 4 bytes per pixel
        final int screenBytes = screenWidth * screenHeight * 4;

        return screenBytes * 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that mNetworkImageView or mContext is null.

Comment: @Santosh salunke but why they arr null ? I am sending them values as its shown in the code

Comment: You should initialize mNetworkImageView and mContext from onCreate method. This should be done below setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); line. In your onCreate method, I don't see any initialization of mNetworkImageView.

Comment: Oh you are right add it as answrr to accept tganks man